# acts_as_taggable_on whitelisted strong parameters still unpermitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, acts-as-taggable-on

Bashing my head against the wall with this one. I have implemented acts_as_taggable_on but even though I have whitelisted the parameters (as in the documentation) I am getting an unpermitted parameters error.

Cannot figure out why.

All help appreciated.

In course.rb

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills
  [...]
end
```

In courses_controller.rb

```
 [...]

 def update
@course.skill_list = params[:skill_list]

respond_to do |format|
  if @course.update(course_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @course }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(:name, :headline, :user_provider_name, :provider_id, :cost, :location, :duration, :skill_level, :no_provider, :format, :website, :contact, :description, review: [:headline, :body, :course_id, :user_id, :score], :skills => [], :skill_list => [])
end
```

If :skills isn't an array it raises an error also.

In _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :skills %><br>
<%= f.text_field :skill_list %>
```

From the log:

```
Started PATCH "/courses/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-24 23:10:40 +0000
Processing by CoursesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"A/4NFlFKwOU/tPQxfbMfh8vsu1dD4lGplqIbna1kooU=", "course"=>{"name"=>"Test course", "skill_list"=>"coding, html, debugging", "cost"=>"", "location"=>"", "duration"=>"", "skill_level"=>"", "format"=>"", "website"=>"", "contact"=>"", "headline"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Course", "id"=>"15"}
  [1m[35mCourse Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "courses".* FROM "courses"  WHERE "courses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
  [1m[36mActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? AND (taggings.context = 'skills' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)[0m  [["taggable_id", 15], ["taggable_type", "Course"]]
Unpermitted parameters: skill_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to was to remove the `acts_as_taggable_on :skills` from my model and replace `:skill_list => []` with `:tag_list`

I guess this loses the multiple tag functionality of acts_as_taggable_on, but at least it gets it working